# jquery ajax return nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm using **ruby on rails + jquery ajax**

My function is for **user check availability for new user registration.**

```
function checkavailablity(){
    var username = jQuery("#user_email").val();
    var allNodes = 'name=' + username;
    var capture;

    if ((username).length > 0) {

        jQuery('#availability').show().text("Checking...");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/user_available",
            data: allNodes,
            success: function(result) {
                // Call this function on success
        alert(result);
//            showResponseRegisterCheck( result );
//            return result;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
        }

        });
    } else {
        jQuery('#availability').addClass('show_msg');
        jQuery('#availability').show().text('Please enter a valid email id');
        return false;
    }   
}
```

===========================================================================

and on rails my method is

```
def user_available
    render :nothing => true
    p user_email = params[:name]
    p @user_email = User.where("email = ?",user_email).first
    if @user_email.nil?
      @ww = "yes"
    else
      @ww = "no"
    end
    return @ww

  end
```

=====================================================================

**my problem is** 
In my ajax-sucess I got no output but 
 **in my rails method I'm returning yes or no** value.

Comment: Check for the JS error if any... is your success method is alerting???

Comment: Yes, It is alerting but result is blank.

Comment: It doesn't seems like the rails function is outputting any value, I don't know any ruby on rails, but I don't think that just returning the value of the ww variable will work, you actually need it to be __printed__. In PHP for example you use echo or other functions to print the value, try printing the value in your ruby on rails script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about changes like followings.

```
- render :nothing => true
- return @ww
+ render :text => @ww  #at the last line
```